# Contentloader with $_GET[] parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I like to use a "Contentloader", but I have a little problem.

**URL-Syntax:** `http://example.com/?s=page`

My "*page*.php" is load on index.php and you can find this file in "pages/page.php".

I´ve got this javascript to load this page:

```
$('#navigation ul li a').click(function() {
    var attribute = $('#navigation ul li a').attr('href');
    $('#content').load(attribute);
        return false;
});
```

Now, the whole website was load again in `<div id="content"></div>`.
This is my problem.

I like to load only the content of "pages/page.php" with a simply contentloader and I don´t know how I can fix this.

This is the PHP-Code to load the content:

```
<div id="content">
            <?php
                $includeDir = ".".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."pages".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                $includeDefault = $includeDir."startseite.php"; 

                if(isset($_GET['s']) && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
                    $_GET['s'] = str_replace("\0", '', $_GET['s']);
                    $includeFile = basename(realpath($includeDir.$_GET['s'].".php"));
                    $includePath = $includeDir.$includeFile;

                    if (!empty($includeFile) && file_exists($includePath)) {
                        include($includePath);
                    } else {
                       include($includePath."404.html");
                    }       
                } else {
                    include($includeDefault);
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

here is a example of a file in the directory:

```
<h2>Example</h2> <p>This is an example</p>
```

I hope, you can help me.
(i am sorry about my bad english!)

Comment: did you check what the value of 'attirbute' is in the debugger?

Comment: attribute gives back "?s=page". it´s logical that the loader output the whole website again, because he loads "example.com/index.php?s=page" in <div id="content"></div>. i don´t know how i can fix it

Comment: You'll have to write PHP code to listen for $_GET['s'] and then load different content when $_GET['s'] == 'page'

Comment: i dont know what you mean, but i´ve wrote already a php code to load different contents with $_GET[]. i like to load the content with javascript (ajax), that a refresh of the website isn´t necessary

Comment: Can you post complete code so we can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: i have add the php code to the main post. this is the complete code.

Comment: remove the !empty() check, as that is doing more or less the same as isset(). Have you debugged your code to see what your PHP page is getting in $_GET[s]?

Answer (score 0):

1) You have div#content in your index.php and also the server response when client requests for s=page. Remove the div wrapper should solve the duplicate div#content problem.

2) Whenever you allow client to provide input which will in turn fetch a file in your server, make sure you do enough work to validate user's input, as someone can use an input like **s=../../../../etc/passwd** against your php server (assuming it's running on *nix).